# flask sqlalchemy query filter relationship

Tags: python, relationship, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 2 models: Post and Comment, a post has many comments, how can I filter posts whose comments.count() is smaller than 2?

```
Post: id(primary key), body, author_id, comments
Comment: id(primary key), body, author_id, post_id
```

where,

```
comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='post', lazy='dynamic')
```

thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can find a solution better than scanning the whole table.

For better efficiency, you can add a field(with index) `num_comments` to the post table, and update it whenever a new comment comming.